# About a change in 0.8.6 - free transactions with less than 0.01 outputs

Tags: bitcoin-core, dust

```
// This code can be removed after enough miners have upgraded to version 0.9.
// Until then, be safe when sending and require a fee if any output
// is less than CENT:
if (nMinFee < nBaseFee && mode == GMF_SEND)
{
    BOOST_FOREACH(const CTxOut& txout, tx.vout)
        if (txout.nValue < CENT)
            nMinFee = nBaseFee;
}
```

The above if clause was as below:

```
if (nMinFee < nBaseFee)
```

Gavin explains this change as:

> Remove the rule that all outputs of free transactions must be greater
>   than 0.01 XBT. Dust spam is now taken care of by making dusty outputs non-standard.

I don't see any other code change in the [same commit](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/ea1cd5b47f473eed60b3ed95853b053e9f686d69). How is dust spam taken care of? Was it made non-standard in a previous version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, "dust" transactions were made nonstandard in commit [`8de9bb53`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/8de9bb53af32f7f6b09c06f831f2c0a7b4e95303):

> Define dust transaction outputs, and make them non-standard